# Using class field names in JSP as input names

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Let's assume I have the following trivial bean:

```
class Dog {
    private String nickname;
    // .. getters and setters
```

And my servlet reads it as a bean:

```
<jsp:useBean id="dog" class="Dog" scope="request"/> 
<jsp:setProperty name="dog" property="*"/>
```

If my form contains:

```
    <input type="text" name="nickname">
```

it works, but when I refactor Dog, renaming some of the fields, e.g. :

```
class Dog {
    private String nickname-->name;
    // .. getters and setters
```

The system stops working silently and the bean is not populated.

I'd love to be able to write something like this:

```
    Nickname: <input type="text" name="<%=Fields(Dog.class).nickname%>">
```

Then, when I rename/reactor Dog, and the field name changes, the form JSP will stop compiling and I'll know I have some renaming to do...

What would be my best tool?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider to use ajax for this scenario? after all, you don't want to post your page to the server in a synchronized approach.

Comment: @MosheArad , I'm not sure what the suggestion is, I can make the submit sync/async but the question is how I make sure that the html variable names match Java bean fields.